# Why signed applet couldn't write files to the client file system using firefox?

Tags: java, firefox, applet

I have an applet (java) that writes some files to the client file system. In Chrome and IE work perfectly and firefox too, only if I run it with Administrator permissions . (righ click -> Run as administrator). This solution don't look proper for a enterprise application.

By the way the applet is part of a big enterprise web application. So I don't have the security that the clients will be able to run firefox as administrator.

Comment: give the complete stacktrace (if there is an exception), or describe what the problem is, if there is no exception

Comment: The exception was about IO File permission denied. I can't write files... I need a location where I can writes files in the client machine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to store application data is in a sub-directory of user.home.  Use a sub-directory based on the package name of the main class, to help avoid your 'settings.dat' colliding with our 'settings.dat'!

---

To make it even more 'Windows friendly' (when the relevant property indicates Win. of course!) the root directory for settings for any Java app. might be ${user.home}/AppData/Local/Java/

Comment: Thank you for the idea. The code in Java is: System.getProperty("user.home") to get the path to the user home directory. See ya!

Answer (score 1):

Can it be that it's Firefox itself that doesn't have permissions to write where you want it to write to?

Comment: umm no.. I don't think so. I'm writing in ".", inside the firefox, inside the user's firefox local data. This is the place where I have the security that the applet wiil be able to write. In other part of the file system I don't not sure of the permissions.

Comment: I'd say that "." is very likely candidate to a problem cause. Microsoft warns against using the concept of current directory for multithreaded applications, especially heavily multithreaded ones. So I guess this *is* the problem. For testing purposes you can use the absolute path, to which you surely know Firefox has access to (something like c:\temp). This way you'll narrow down the problem.